# Getting top 5 highest numbers from across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows and I am trying to make a query and obtain the top 5 numbers across all the pay columns and the associated name to that number.

I am using Java and I could derive the data by selecting them all and get the information.

Intention is to loop through them, store first 5 numbers in an array and keep updating the array if the next number is higher than that ones present in the array. Which means looping through the array each time to check against the new number.

Is there a more efficient way and I could do everything in MySQL query itself?

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZarB.jpg)

**Expected results would be:**

```
1200 Simon
1150 jenny
1000 alan
900  james
800  alan
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why don't you try to solve it yourself and let us know how it goes? And when you do, you'll need to tell us about your schema.

Comment: 1. See normalisation 2. Normalise your data

Comment: In this instance, a normalised table might have 3 columns instead of 5